# binwalk gives an endless list of files

Tags: binwalk

I am running `binwalk -B image.bin` on an 8MB firmware that I dumped from an MStar MSC313e based ip camera. The binwalk output is longer than I would expect. Could they be mostly false positives?

I have assumed that the squashfs parts are detected properly, and I have successfully unsquashed the 3 squashfs at

- 0x210000 (len 0x430000): squashfs_1_out
- 0x640000 (len 0x90000): squashfs_2_out
- 0x6D0000 (len 0xFFF32): squashfs_3_out

Then I have assumed that and jffs2 at 0x530000-0x640000 is 1 big jffs2 and successfully extracted it

- 0x530000 (len 0x110000): jffs2_out

```
.
├── jffs2_out
│   ├── asnvdvrclientdemo
│   ├── audiofile_player
│   └── wificonf
│       ├── RT2870AP
│       └── RT2870STA
├── squashfs_1_out
│   ├── bin
│   ├── etc
│   │   ├── bak
│   │   │   └── reset
│   │   └── init.d
│   ├── font
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── libc
│   │   └── modules
│   │       └── 3.18.30
│   └── usr
│       ├── bin
│       ├── lib
│       └── share
├── squashfs_2_out
│   └── modules
└── squashfs_3_out
    ├── apps
    ├── demo
    ├── iq
    ├── lib
    └── modules
```

How would you go about this?

Entropy plot:

[image: Entropy plot]

Binwalk output:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
95704         0x175D8         CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
98216         0x17FA8         xz compressed data
196608        0x30000         uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x4E02B7B8, created: 2018-05-04 01:36:00, image size: 97660 bytes, Data Address: 0x0, Entry Point: 0x0, data CRC: 0xC803513A, OS: Firmware, CPU: ARM, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: lzma, image name: "MVX1##I3g#######CM_UBT1501###XVM"
196672        0x30040         xz compressed data
393216        0x60000         uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x18637732, created: 2019-05-22 04:21:22, image size: 1648896 bytes, Data Address: 0x20008000, Entry Point: 0x20008000, data CRC: 0xC0344FAC, OS: Linux, CPU: ARM, image type: Multi-File Image, compression type: lzma, image name: "MVX2##I3gbeb3a68KL_LX318####[BR:"
393292        0x6004C         xz compressed data
1967368       0x1E0508        xz compressed data
2162688       0x210000        Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, compression:xz, size: 3191278 bytes, 245 inodes, blocksize: 131072 bytes, created: 2019-05-22 04:21:30
5439488       0x530000        JFFS2 filesystem, little endian
5505128       0x540068        JFFS2 filesystem, little endian
5505608       0x540248        JFFS2 filesystem, little endian
5534392       0x5472B8        JFFS2 filesystem, little endian
5534580       0x547374        Zlib compressed data, compressed
5534756       0x547424        Zlib compressed data, compressed
5534932       0x5474D4        Zlib compressed data, compressed
5535108       0x547584        Zlib compressed data, compressed
5535284       0x547634        Zlib compressed data, compressed
[... snip snap 380 Zlib/JFFS2 lines omitted...]
6420404       0x61F7B4        JFFS2 filesystem, little endian
6422676       0x620094        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6423024       0x6201F0        JFFS2 filesystem, little endian
6460760       0x629558        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6461188       0x629704        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6461616       0x6298B0        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6462044       0x629A5C        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6462472       0x629C08        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6462900       0x629DB4        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6463328       0x629F60        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6463760       0x62A110        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6464192       0x62A2C0        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6464624       0x62A470        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6465056       0x62A620        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6465488       0x62A7D0        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6465920       0x62A980        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6466352       0x62AB30        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6466784       0x62ACE0        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6467216       0x62AE90        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6467648       0x62B040        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6468080       0x62B1F0        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6468512       0x62B3A0        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6468944       0x62B550        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6469376       0x62B700        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6469808       0x62B8B0        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6470240       0x62BA60        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6470672       0x62BC10        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6471104       0x62BDC0        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6471536       0x62BF70        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6471968       0x62C120        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6472400       0x62C2D0        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6472832       0x62C480        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6473264       0x62C630        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6473696       0x62C7E0        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6474128       0x62C990        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6474560       0x62CB40        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6474992       0x62CCF0        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6475424       0x62CEA0        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6475856       0x62D050        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6476288       0x62D200        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6476720       0x62D3B0        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6477348       0x62D624        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6477716       0x62D794        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6478148       0x62D944        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6478580       0x62DAF4        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6479340       0x62DDEC        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6479772       0x62DF9C        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6480204       0x62E14C        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6480640       0x62E300        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6481076       0x62E4B4        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6481508       0x62E664        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6481940       0x62E814        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6482372       0x62E9C4        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6482804       0x62EB74        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6483236       0x62ED24        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6483668       0x62EED4        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6484100       0x62F084        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6484532       0x62F234        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6484964       0x62F3E4        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6485396       0x62F594        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6485828       0x62F744        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6486260       0x62F8F4        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6486688       0x62FAA0        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6487116       0x62FC4C        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6487544       0x62FDF8        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6488064       0x630000        JFFS2 filesystem, little endian
6553600       0x640000        Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, compression:xz, size: 575890 bytes, 15 inodes, blocksize: 131072 bytes, created: 2019-04-16 09:59:10
7143424       0x6D0000        Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, compression:xz, size: 1048370 bytes, 52 inodes, blocksize: 131072 bytes, created: 2019-05-22 09:58:29
```